# VLC player slide show flickering

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am using VLC player to play a set of images(in PNG format) in full screen like an advertisement board - except I use it for decoration, sometimes announcement.

The problem is when the player tries to change between two images of different resolution, it will close the window the current image is displayed in and open another. This result in a half second where the empty player with the border and controls are visible.

Is there a method to make the transition between these image smooth?

If it matters, I play the images by using the `open multiple files` option under `media` then add the images and play from it.